# AxiosInstance and isAxiosError

Tags: typescript, axios

- I'm using Typescript
- I like to pre-configure my base URL for all my requests

As far as I understood I need to create an instance of axios to set my default base URL like this:

```
 axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/v1/' ;
 const axios_instance : AxiosInstance = axios.create();
```

I then inject `axios_instance` into all my classes which need to do requests. This works as expected. The problem occurs in the catch method of request functions. E.g.:

```
this.axios_instance.post<AddUserResponse>(
  ...
)
.then(...)
.catch((err: Error | AxiosError) => {
 if (this.axios_instance.isAxiosError(err)) {
      console.log('error message: ', err.message);
      throw err.message;
    } else {
        // Just a stock error
        console.log('unexpected error: ', err);
         throw err;
     }
   });
```

`isAxiosError()` is not a function on `AxiosInstance`, but on `AxiosStatic` (which derives from `AxiosInstance`)

How would I use `isAxiosError()` when working with instances? Or how should I handle axios errors if `isAxiosError()` is not available?

Comment: If you set the `axios.defaults.baseURL` then that applies to _all_ calls, you don't need to `.create` an instance. The instance would be `axios.create({ baseURL })` if you wanted other requests to _not_ use that base URL. Also you can still use `axios.isAxiosError(err)` statically there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I got it working. Turned out that I had a naming scope problem, hence I couldn't use the `AxiosStatic` as intended. After that worked, I got rid of the instances and it's still working. If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isAxiosError` exposes on `axios` object, see [v1.4.0/dist/axios.js#L2968](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.4.0/dist/axios.js#L2968)

```js
// Expose isAxiosError
axios.isAxiosError = isAxiosError;
```

So you can use it like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.isAxiosError(new Error('network')) // false
```